# Difference between "umgezogen" and "verzogen"

Tags: difference

What is the difference between "umgezogen" and "verzogen"? Or is it just the same? Especially "umgezogen nach" and "verzogen nach" seem to be exactly the same. Just the combination with "unbekannt" seems to be exclusively used with "verzogen".

Comment: I first misread *ungezogen* instead of *umgezogen,* which interestingly would also make for a valid question.

Comment: A French translation of verzogen on Google Translate is "perverted" in English, which has nothing to do with umgezogen :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With regard to moving, there's no difference at all. Both verbs convey the idea of changing your address.
*Verziehen*, however, is rarely used; only occurs in the form *verzogen sein* or *unbekannt verzogen*.

You're always on the safe side using *umziehen* (or *wegziehen*, *fortziehen*, meaning *to move away*).

Both verbs have more meanings, but there's no further overlap.

Answer (score 7):

1 Wir sind nach München umgezogen - meaning we have moved house and live now in Munich.

2 If a letter is turned back to the post office with the remark "verzogen" this means the addessee has moved house, but his new address is unknown.

3 ein verzogenes Kind has no manners because the parents don't know anything about child-raising.

Answer (score 5):

In German *[ziehen](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=ziehen)* (to pull) is used as a stem for a variety of verbs relatied to moving house. Of course the meaning *ziehen* is not restricted to moving alone, sometimes the same prefix is used with an entirely different meaning:

> **umziehen:** *to move (house)* also *to change clothes*
>   **wegziehen:** *to move away* also *to draw away*
>   **ausziehen:** *to move out* also *to take of clothes*
>   **einziehen:** *to move in*  also *to feed in, to infiltrate, to contract*
>   **zuziehen:** *to move to* also *to pull tight*
>   **verziehen:** only used in the past with participle **ist/war verzogen**: *moved away* also *spoiled, spoilt, skewed*
>   **umherziehen:** *to tramp, to rove around*
>   **nachziehen:** *to partly move later (e.g. family)* also *to (re)tighten, to limp ("ein Bein nachziehen")*
>   **beziehen:** *to move into* also *to obtain, to draw, to drap ...*
>
> ...
>
> **herziehen, fortziehen, zusammenziehen,** ... and likely many more - also see other answers

Comment: "beziehen" as a synonym for "einziehen" could be added to the list - or is this a different stem? And then there are still amazingly many variants of "ziehen" that have no meaning related to "moving house": hinein-, heraus-, hoch-, herunter-, hinunter-, an-, ab-, mit-, entgegen-, über-, durch-, rein-, groß-  and erziehen (and even "einbeziehen").

Comment: ah, and of course "fortziehen" (see Em1's answer)

Comment: Nice collection. I doubt that any questions about *ziehen* are left over. Some further, just for reference: *herziehen*, *zusammenziehen*. Different: *vorziehen*.

Comment: Thanks for all these suggestions... edited that in an made it CW for anybody who wants to further add some.

Answer (score 0):

I would use "umgezogen" if i knew where exactly they have have moved.
otherwise, i would use "verzogen". 
If i know the city or region, i might say "verzogen nach [region/city]".

I think "verzogen" therefore can also express that you are not willing to tell (the person who asked) their new adress.

On the other hand, when my answer is simply "Sie sind umgezogen", you can suggest that i also know where they moved, and ask me for the adress in your next question.