# Senden, Schicken, and Verschicken

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

It seems that *senden*, *schicken*, and *verschicken* all mean "to send" in some way. *Senden* is a little easier to distinguish since *schicken* and *verschicken* both share the definition "to dispatch," but what really is the proper use case for these words? For example, when uploading a photo to Instagram, my phone says "Wird gesendet." However, I would suspect that "to dispatch" might be a little more appropriate than "to send" in this case. So why not *schicken* or *verschicken*?

Answer (score 15):

To me, "senden" has a duration, in particular when talking about radio or Internet, but also to some extent when talking about letters (meaning that it takes a while until they reach you).

"Schicken" (and "verschicken") on the other hand gives more the impression of a one-time action, like posting a letter into a mailbox.

But the lines are quite blurry between the two and often they are interchangeable ("wird verschickt" in your example sounds perfectly fine to me), while in some instances their use is idiomatic.

Comment: +1 for duration. For the prefix `ver-` see also [this question](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15832/) about `umziehen` und `verziehen`. Note that the thing you dispatch is always a `Sendung` :)

Comment: I cannot understand this "duration" distinction at all. "Posting a letter" and "sending an email" are one time-actions and, in both cases, it takes some time until the content arrives. Could somebody explain it better?

Answer (score 6):

"Senden" has a somewhat technical meaning, it is often used in the context of a radio or wireless transmission. It is certainly appropiate in the context of a smartphone.

Comment: I have read in my German textbook: "Soll ich Ihnen noch eine Bestätigung senden?". I suppose this could refer to sending a letter or an email. I suppose "senden" could be replaced by "schicken" in this sentence without any change in meaning?